# Getting information from an armored gpg public key file

Tags: linux, gnupg, gnu

When given a file with an armored public GnuPG key, i.e. a file (`pubkey.gpg`) that was created with:

```
gpg -r 0xDEADBEEF --export --armored > pubkey.gpg
```

What is the best way to get information such as the finger print in that file, without importing it into my keyring?

The best way I found so far (and I am not happy with) is:

```
gpg --dry-run --import pubkey.gpg
```

Naturally, I grepped the gpg man page, but didn't find an obvious solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know that gpg has an option for this, but here's a more flexible workaround for extracting information from the key file:

```
mkdir temp-gnupg-dir
export GNUPGHOME=temp-gnupg-dir
gpg --import pubkey.gpg
gpg --list-keys
rm -r temp-gnupg-dir
```

Instead of the `GNUPGHOME` environment variable, you can pass `--homedir=temp-gnupg-dir` to every gpg invocation.

Comment: This is not pretty, but it is useful to know what options are *not* available, and this *is* a solution. So I thank you for that.

Comment: While this will work, it's way more complicated than necessary. Below I posted how to do it without any of the importing or keychain switching.

Answer (score 18):

To print the fingerprint of an on-disk armored key without importing it, just use `--with-fingerprint`:

```
> gpg --with-fingerprint jm3.asc

pub  1024R/9112BC51 1996-02-05 john manoogian <jm3@*>
Key fingerprint = C9 DC 27 29 0E 1A DB 50  21 C8 64 08 15 29 41 86

uid                            john manoogian <jm3@foo...
uid                            john manoogian <jm3@bar...
uid                            john manoogian <jm3@baz...
uid                            john manoogian <jm3@qux...
```

Voilà!

Comment: This will create a gnupg directory and a default keyring if one does not exist. The accepted answer does not have that side-effect.

Comment: `--with-fingerprint` is [optional](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27300700/52499).

Comment: This no longer works. My gpg version is 2.2.5.

Answer (score 6):

You can checkout Kazu Yamamoto's PGP packet visualizer which displays the packet format of OpenPGP (RFC 4880) and PGP version 2 (RFC 1991).

To fetch and compile:

```
git clone http://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/pgpdump
cd pgpdump
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ && make && sudo make install
```

Using it is even simpler:

```
pgpdump pubkey.gpg
```

There is also a cgi-bin interface available on this site: http://www.pgpdump.net/cgi-bin/pgpdump

Comment: This is awesome! And kudos to a fellow Haskeller Kazu :)

BTW, pgpdump is packaged by Debian (and possibly other distros, too), so check it in the repositories before compiling it yourself.

Comment: There's a similar to _pgpdump_ but not that verbose output from `gpg --list-packets`

Answer (score 0):

There is more simple solution (tested for GnuPG 2.2.27):

```
gpg pubkey.gpg
```

Or, machine-readable result (some upgrades for @jm3 answer):

```
gpg --with-fingerprint --with-colons pubkey.gpg
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).